# Macaulay2 to latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, conversion

Is there a way to generate the output of Macaulay2 computations to latex? For example, I can do the following:

```
i1 : R = QQ[a,b,c,d]

o1 = R

o1 : PolynomialRing

i2 : I = ideal (a*b, c*d)

o2 = ideal (a*b, c*d)

o2 : Ideal of R

i3 : freeI = res I

       1      2      1
o3 = R  <-- R  <-- R  <-- 0

     0      1      2      3

o3 : ChainComplex

i4 : freeI.dd

          1                 2
o4 = 0 : R  <------------- R  : 1
               | ab cd |

          2                   1
     1 : R  <--------------- R  : 2
               {2} | -cd |
               {2} | ab  |

          1
     2 : R  <----- 0 : 3
               0

o4 : ChainComplexMap
```

Can I generate the last output, the resolution with matrices and all, as latex code?

EDIT: I would like to get what the following code outputs (I can't get pictures in here in a good way), or something like it:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{tikzcd}
    0 \arrow{r} & R^2 \arrow{r}{\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}} & R^2 \arrow{r}{(ab, cd)} & R \arrow{r}{} & M \arrow{r} & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Just the matrices are fine too, if there is a way to get them.

Comment: how about you downvoters leave a comment on how to improve this question?

Comment: @naphaneal For example as in my suggestion. (I am not a downvoter here).

Comment: Thank you for pointing an interesting tool. Including the expected LaTeX output for your example could help in thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the matrices using the `tex X` command that theoretically gives tex code for any object X in Macaulay2. For example, the first map in your resolution can be obtained by

```
i15 : tex freeI.dd#1

o15 = $\bgroup\begin{pmatrix}a b&
      c d\\
      \end{pmatrix}\egroup$
```

Calling `tex` again you can also get the resolution (without the maps)

```
i16 : tex freeI

o16 = $R \leftarrow R^{2} \leftarrow R \leftarrow 0$
```

Unfortunately, if you try to apply the `tex` command to the whole resolution, the results are the totally unsatisfying

```
i14 : tex freeI.dd
o14 = $ChainComplexMap{...6...}$
```

So we don't get all the way to the TeX of the full resolution as you desire but it's possible to piece that together from the resolution and the matrices quite quickly with the help of a decent text editor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.